# Not getting list of Objects from View to Controller in Asp.net Core 6 MVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created Purchase Order Master Detail Form in asp.net core MVC, where I am passing all the detail section to controller via AJAX Call. I have created array to contain list of objects of order detail and passing that array to controller via AJAX Post method but i am getting null in parameter in controller. Please help. please have a look at my code.

On Submit button i call this function AddPO() to save my Purchase Order.
JavaScript function .cshtml page

```
function AddPO() {
            debugger;
            var objPOHeaderViewModel = {};
            var ListofPOLineViewModel = new Array();

            objPOHeaderViewModel.PODate = $('#PODate').val();
            objPOHeaderViewModel.PONumber = $('#PONumber').val();
            objPOHeaderViewModel.DeliveryDt = $('#DeliveryDt').val();
            objPOHeaderViewModel.ExchangeRate = $('#ExchangeRate').val();
            objPOHeaderViewModel.VendorId = $('#VendorId').val();
            objPOHeaderViewModel.VendorName = $('#VendorAddress').val();
            objPOHeaderViewModel.VendorAddress = $('#VendorAddress').val();
            objPOHeaderViewModel.RefernceNo = $('#RefernceNo').val();
            objPOHeaderViewModel.PaymentTerms = $('#PaymentTerms').val();
            objPOHeaderViewModel.Remarks = $('#Remarks').val();
            objPOHeaderViewModel.Total = $('#Total').val();


            $('#tblPOLine').find('tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
                var POLineViewModel = {};
                POLineViewModel.ItmId = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();
                POLineViewModel.Code = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();
                POLineViewModel.UOM = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text();
                POLineViewModel.Rate = parseFloat($(this).find('td:eq(7)').text());
                POLineViewModel.Qty = parseFloat($(this).find('td:eq(7)').text());
                POLineViewModel.Disc = parseFloat($(this).find('td:eq(7)').text());
                POLineViewModel.SubTotal = parseFloat($(this).find('td:eq(7)').text());
                ListofPOLineViewModel.push(POLineViewModel);
            });
           
            objPOHeaderViewModel.Polines = ListofPOLineViewModel;

          
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(objPOHeaderViewModel),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                url: '/PONew/SaveOrderw',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Errorrrrr.");
                }
            });
        }
```

This is my model class

```
public class POHeaderViewModel
    {
        public string PONumber { get; set; } = "";
        public string VendorId { get; set; } = "";
        public string VendorName { get; set; } = "";
        public string? VendorAddress { get; set; }
        public string? PODate { get; set; } 
        public string? DeliveryDt { get; set; }
        public string? RefernceNo { get; set; }
        public string? ExchangeRate { get; set; }
        public string? PaymentTerms { get; set; }
        public string? Remarks { get; set; }
        public string? Total { get; set; }
        public List<POLineViewModel> Polines { get; set; }
    }

 public class POLineViewModel
    {
        public string ItmId {get; set;}
        public string? Code {get; set;} = "";
        public string? UOM {get; set;} = "";
        public decimal Rate {get; set;}
        public decimal Qty {get; set;}
        public decimal? Disc {get; set;}
        public decimal? SubTotal {get; set;}
    }
```

This is my controller function

```
 public JsonResult SaveOrderw(POHeaderViewModel objPOHeaderViewModel)
        {
            return Json(data: "Successfully added.");
        }
```

I have not added additional details of controller function right now because my issue is i am getting **POHeaderViewModel objPOHeaderViewModel** null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Asp.Net Core MVC, The parameter in action will bind value from the form by default. But in your ajax, You send data by the type of `application/json`, So parameter need to bind value from body instead of form. Here you need to add `[FromBody]` attribute to make parameter bind value from request body instead of form:

```
public JsonResult SaveOrderw([FromBody]POHeaderViewModel objPOHeaderViewModel)
{
}
```

You can also refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75320000/ajax-call-not-send-the-data-to-controller/75320070#75320070).